# ASP.NET Checkbox.Checked is not working

Tags: c#, asp.net, checkbox, checked

In [asp.net](/questions/tagged/asp.net) Webforms I have a `CheckBox` and `Button`.

```
<asp:CheckBox ID="checkBox" runat="server" />
<asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Check" OnClick="Button1_Click"/>
```

I want to handle `Checkbox`'s check status with `ButtonClick`. But it is only getting false value.

```
if (checkBox.Checked == (true))
{
    Label1.Text = "Selected";
}
else
{
    Label1.Text = "Not Selected";
}
```

After every `click` I am getting Not Selected in my `Label`. I think this is so basic but now I couldn't fix.

Is there anyway to fix this.

Comment: try checkbox.value

Comment: in Webforms it is not possible

Comment: Please show us the whole method that contains the `if (checkBox.Checked == ... ` part (or at least its full name and declaration).

Comment: Maybe it needs DataBound before the checking its value.

Comment: I tried its working perfectly fine.... recheck for minute mistakes

Comment: You probably overwrite the value when doing a PostBack. See if setting the initial value is wrapped inside an `IsPostBack` check. Or is the checkbox located in a GridView, Repeater etc?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not sure if this has been solved, this is beacause Autopostback is not enabled.
Change it to below

````
    asp:CheckBox ID="checkBox" AutoPostBack=“true” runat="server"  ```
````