# ASP.NET C#: OnCheckedChanged event processing inside of UpdatePanel

Tags: c#, asp.net, checkbox, updatepanel, autopostback

While creating my login-form, I need a checkbox option, allowing user to show `<asp:TextBox TextMode="Password">` input, or hide it back again, but it seems my `<asp:CheckBox ID="chkShowPass">` does not process `chkShowPass_CheckedChange` event. I found an article on this topic ([ASP.NET Checkbox.Checked is not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45568108/asp-net-checkbox-checked-is-not-working)), where `chkShowPass.AutoPostBack` property set to `true` settles the problem.

When I have plain ASP.NET example to put `<asp:CheckBox ID="chkShowPass">` in, I'm able to do that with no problem, but the key thing, I have now added `<asp:UpdatePanel>` element to prevent my website pages from auto-scrolling on button-clicks, and to make my good-basket UI (which lies in
*Site.Master*) update properly from those clicks.

What shall I do, to make my `<asp:CheckBox ID="chkShowPass">` react to `chkShowPass_CheckedChange` event, but, still, keeping my *Site.Master*'s content in `<asp:UpdatePanel>`? I will also appreciate, if you know any way to prevent page from upscrolling on click, without `<asp:UpdatePanel>`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it using `jQuery`. give id to `Password Textbox` and a `checkbox`

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#checkbox').click(function(){
            if($(this).is(':checked'))
            {
                $('#password_id').attr('type', 'text');
            }
            else
            {
                $('#password_id').attr('type', 'password');
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

Remember to add `jquery script` in a page.

`<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"></script>`